# How can I execute my script function on the Linux Operating system restart

Tags: linux

I have a script that works perfectly when called manually. Now I am trying to tweak the script, so that when the Linux box is restarted the script will restart the service. I am using RHEL. This is the basic structure of my script. So my question is how can I set it so that when the OS reboots. This script is called with the "restart" condition. The name of the script is bus.sh

PLEASE NOTE. I did place the script in the /etc/rc.d/init.d directory and changed the permissions. Do not know what else I am missing.

```
#!/bin/sh

RETVAL=0

start() {
    echo Starting application
    "/opt/application.sh" start
}
stop() {
    echo Stopping application
    "/opt/application.sh" stop
}
restart() {
    echo Restart application
    "/opt/application.sh" restart
}
status() {
    echo Status application
    "/opt/application.sh" status
}
case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    restart
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVA
```

L

Comment: see ``man chkconfig`` and ``man 7 runlevel`` on redhat-ish systems.

Answer (score 0):

You havent said the name of the script, so lets call it foo ...`/etc/init.d/foo`

To add the service so it starts automatically:

```
chkconfig foo on
```

Now you can start it:

```
service foo start
```

Comment: Probably be an idea to RTFM for chkconfig first especially the bit on the commented "chkconfig:" lines in the init.d scripts

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue. I needed a lock file to be synched